# Changing user role

Tags: wordpress, timer, roles

I have some issues, i don't know how i can do a feature. I need to change user role after 1 month, 3 month, 1 year.

I can change role like this:

```
$u = new WP_User( $user->ID );
// Remove role
$u->remove_role( 'editor' );
// Add role
$u->add_role( 'subscriber' );
```

But i can't triger this in time line...

In user_edit panel i add input, where i can put some value:

```
$date_change =  get_the_author_meta( 'date_change', $user->ID );
<input type="text" name="date_change" id="date_change"
 class="regular-text" value="<?php echo $date_change; ?>" />
```

Next i'm trying to trigger this, like so:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'editor' ) );
// Array of WP_User objects.
if($date_change == '3'){
foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
   $kkk = $user->ID;
   $u = new WP_User( $kkk );
   // Remove role
   $u->remove_role( 'editor' );
   // Add role
   $u->add_role( 'subscriber' );
     }
```

This isn't working for me, it's working if i put (new WP_User and below) outside of "IF" or "FOREACH" loops.

Comment: The code you have doesn't do anything at all with dates. I'm also not sure if you're trying to update all users at the same exact time, 3 months after individual registration, etc...

Comment: You right, question is, can i do some kind of trigger, "do something after 3 month" like sleep("3 month"), than do role change. but sleep isn't the right choice.

Comment: Maybe some way to add Jquery timer, that trigers start of php script(role change)

Comment: you need a cron job, wp has wp_cron.